# Getting and using div height only occasionally works

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to get the height of an appended Div with a sentence in it, then set another appended div with an edit button in it to that height. These divs vary in height with the amount of text entered which is grabbed from an input box then put into the appended sentence div. This works for the most part. I append the text div, grab the height using .height(), and the appended edit button div is set to that height.

The problem is that when I put in an exact amount of characters to just barely bring the appended div to a new line, the height grabbed is wrong. Each line has a height of 19px, so usually the grabbed height results in 19, 38, 57, etc. When the approximate amount of characters is entered to just barely increase the height to the next level, a div with a height of 57 is calculated as having a height of 38, and the other appended div is given the wrong height.

It looks like so (cursor hovering over the lowest div in the box): https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WIn2.png

I want the edit button to have height such that the text doesn't slide to the left below it.

I'm using jquery to grab the element height.

```
$("#" + edtBtn.id).css("height", $("#" + newSent.id).outerHeight(true));
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3aa7qu5b/3/ (works best in firefox)

Don't mind the miscellaneous useless buttons and stuff. I tried to keep elements I thought were relevant for placement. Copy/Paste real sentences for realistic results.

Is there any way to fix this?

**EDIT:** I noticed that the amount of characters that upsets the spacing is an amount of characters that fit within the 45px width of the edit button element. In the picture example, the word "work" happens to fit within that spacing. This probably has to do with my instances of transform: translateX in the css. However, my original question still stands.

Comment: Your jsfiddle is not referencing jQuery so the above line of code fails. You did everything else in vanilla JS though, why not do this in it too?

Comment: after what @br4d.net have pointed out about no references to jQuery in jsfiddle, I made these reference to be active that links to jQuery, then script doesn't work compared to the original result.

Comment: @Faron Forgive me if I'm wrong about this, but is it not possible to select jquery in the "framework and extensions" part of the sidebar in jsfiddle as I have done? Setting it to pure JS certainly breaks my code, but it works with "jQuery 2.1.3" selected.

Comment: @br4d.net I tried multiple ways with vanilla js, and none of them got even close to working like that one simple line of jquery does.

Comment: It's usually helpful to hit these things with the dev tools or at least throw an outline style rule on the element you're having trouble with.  Usually when height is wrong it's because the children are overflowing the parent (overflow: hidden will usually fix that, but it has other side effects)

Comment: @Jason Yes, hiding the overflow for Y in this case doesn't do a whole lot... I tried float: left on my sentence div to see if it would just stop getting underneath my edit button div, but it doesn't seem to have any positive effect either...

What did you mean by an outline style rule?

Comment: A quick dirty fix might be to just add the css rule   `.sentenceText { padding-left: 50px; }`

Comment: @br4d.net Yeah, I essentially ended up doing something like that... `.sentenceText {float: left; max-width: 90%;}` Since it fit that way with the translateX applied to the other elements. padding might work better though, I'll give it a shot... thanks for your help!

**EDIT:** gave padding a shot, and it looks a lot nicer (gives me a little space between the edit div and the sentences div) on top of being a hotfix for the issue... If you submit this as an answer I'll accept it.